# Bitstamp API POST request with parameters

Tags: c#, api

please, help me with POST api request in C#.I dont know how to correctly send parameters „key“, „signature“ and „nonce“ in POST request. It constantly tells me "Missing key, signature and nonce parameters“.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest =(HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/balance/");
   if (webRequest != null)
   {
       webRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
       webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
       webRequest.UserAgent = "BitstampBot";
       byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(apisecret);
       string nonce = GetNonce().ToString();
       var prehash = nonce + custID + apikey;
       string signature = HashString(prehash, data);
       body = Serialize(new
       {
           key=apikey,
           signature=signature,
           nonce=nonce
       });

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
       {
           var data1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
           webRequest.ContentLength = data1.Length;
           using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream()) stream.Write(data1, 0, data1.Length);
       }
       using (Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
       {
           using (StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
           {
               contentBody = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                   return contentBody;
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Request parameters" as Bitstamp specifies in the [docs](https://www.bitstamp.net/api/) is actually supposed to be sent with content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "application/json".

I would also use HttpClient to perform the post as that has a much more simple setup to perform Http requests

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", apikey),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("signature", signature),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("nonce", nonce)
    });
    var result = await client.PostAsync("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/balance/", content);
    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: I can't find where is specified how to do a POST (users_transactions).