# BitStamp Error:"POST only Endpoint" not recognizing my post request

Tags: httpwebrequest, postman

I'm not sure if this question is for SO, first I thought it was a problem from my code, but then I tried Postman and I got the same error response. I'm trying to use Bitstamp API to execute a buy order (or sell, it's the same), but the API returns "POST Only Endpoint", but I'm 100% sure that `request.Method = "POST"`. I've implemented the [Account Balance](https://www.bitstamp.net/api/) API call which is also POST and everything is fine with it. But for some I can't get the buy/sell API call to work.

Here are some pictures proofing that I'm indeed sending a POST request, after that a picture from POSTMAN. Has someone else got this problem?
[image: Code]

[image: PostMan]

Comment: Have you tried adding those details as url request params in Postman and not as a urlencoded header? Does it tell you to use that header for the request?

Comment: Tried it now. Still the same problem. According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796359/4138686 this is the right way, also the fact that the "Account Balance" call uses the same signature (POST + params in request body) and I can issue a successful response both from my code and from Postman

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Postman and in your code, the URL miss a '/' at the end.
I've had the same issue. It was fixed by adding a '/' at the end of the URL.